# Change system font size

Tags: fonts, windows-10

I wish to increase the size of the font used within `explorer.exe` (aka My Computer) to list files/folders. I do not wish to increase/decrease the screen's overall DPI. I'd just like to change the system UI font used by Windows 10. I know how to use the System Registry.

Comment: Here explain how to create a custom DPI, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller?v=t

Comment: Found answer to this question, but it's locked by http://superuser.com/users/73918/dragonlord so I can't add it

Answer (score 11):

Update August 2019: in newer versions of Windows 10, you can increase only the text size in the new 'Make text bigger' option:

Settings > Ease of Access > Vision > Display > Make text bigger

[image: 'Make text bigger' option]

---

Settings > System > Display > Change the size of text, apps and other items

You can adjust the size there.

[image]

---

Or if you want to specifically choose what you want the text size to change for, go to Control Panel > Appearance and Personalisation > Display > Make text and other items larger or smaller.

Here you can change the font size of title bars, menus, message boxes, palette titles, icons or tooltips:

[image]

Comment: This is not what I asked for.  I specifically stated " I do not wish to increase/decrease the screen's overall DPI."  The sliding 100%, 125%, 150% bar changes EVERYTHING. I specifically asked to change the system font size...nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Control Panel > Appearance and Personalisation  is no more available in Windows 10 after the recent "Creators Update".

Answer (score 6):

I also used to be able to do this before the Creators update. But it no longer works natively in Windows. I'm now on Win 10 Creators Update v 1703 (build 15063.413).

They only way I've found to do this now is with Winaero Tweaker.
Winaero Tweaker > Advanced Appearance Settings > Icons, and the bottom setting is "Change Icons font" This lets you change font type,  style and size.

Comment: Any tips for using Winaero?  For me, using a larger font size just does a pixillated zoom. No actual extra detail. I have a lot of Japanese file names and kind of need that extra detail. Pretty pissed about this last windows update.

Comment: windows tweaker (should be alternative to winaero) can not do this.

Comment: Note: you must click change font to change the size of the font, not just to choose a different font.

Answer (score 3):

I use [advchange.exe](https://www.wintools.info/index.php/advanced-system-font-changer) from https://www.wintools.info (from [this](https://superuser.com/a/1265103) answer).

advchange.exe is a plain tiny exe with 75k bytes size that does not need admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

I think the setting you want is in the old Windows 7 style Control Panel. You can get there two ways:

Settings > Advanced Display Settings > Advanced sizing of text and other items
Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display

From there you have a section "Change only the text size", and a drop down menu where you can customize various font sizes. My defaults were at 9. This doesn't change everything (ironically not the Control Panel itself) but it seems to help.

[image: Text size settings window]

Comment: I've used this successfully in Windows 10, but on a newly built PC with Windows 10 Creators Update I can't find it.  Has it been removed?

Comment: Microsoft are trying to do away with the control panel entirely, but it has to be done in small stages. Less and less will be driven by the control panel in subsequent updates. It used to be that you could configure everything, even things you would never even realise could be changed. Now it's a case of "get what you're given and be happy with it".

Answer (score 0):

According to https://winaero.com/change-system-font-windows-10/#comment-26423, it's not possible:

> You can find sizes that possible to change under the “Advanced
> appearance” section. System font doesn’t support it.

One can only replace the name of the font. This suggests a weird idea of just replacing it with a font that is "naturally" larger at whatever size Windows is forcing on us.