# Increase size of windows 10 system font

Tags: windows-10, fonts

Can't find a way to increase the Windows 10 system font size. Don't want to increase everything by reducing the monitor resolution. Most other font sizes can be changed, but I'm stuck with microscope size fonts for taskbars, and other system items.

Does anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/951199/windows-10-system-font-size-change

Answer (score 0):

I am using Winaero Tweaker.   You can find it here. http://winaero.com/

It allows you to change a lot more than fonts.  Here is a screenshot of the main interface.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, under "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display", you have the choice to selectively change the size of any windows text you like.
There is also some text explaining your options, as you have multiple.