# Windows 10 individual system font size change

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts

This question provides context: [Windows 10 system font size change](https://superuser.com/questions/951199/windows-10-system-font-size-change)

In this question is a way to increase system font size by 25%. Also, in liked help I found "create a custom DPI scale".

> Open Screen Resolution by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, and then, under Appearance and Personalization, clicking Adjust screen resolution.
>
> Click Set custom text size (DPI) in the left pane.
>
> Click the scale (ruler), drag the setting to whatever percentage size increase you want (100%-500%), and then click OK. (If you prefer, you can type a number between 100 and 500 in the box next to Scale to this percentage of normal size, and then click OK.)
>
> On the Display screen, click Apply.

However, this is obsolete (Win 7), I am looking for a way to do this on Windows 10.

Comment: [The instructions are early identical](http://pureinfotech.com/2014/10/18/fix-windows-10-dpi-scaling-virtual-machine-high-definition-displays/)  Specifically `System->Advanced display Settings -> Advanced sizing of text and other items`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, indeed, with the fonts used for [MS Shell Dlg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374112(v=vs.85).aspx) which, by default, is [Microsoft Sans Serif](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=244). The latter is described as "metrically compatible with the MS Sans bitmap font" which hints at why high-dpi scaling can get messed up.

Solution: locate

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

in the registry and change `MS Shell Dlg` to something else - `Arial` or `Tahoma` will work, but to look like the rest of Windows I chose `Segoe UI`.

Comment: I believe OP asked about how to change the size of the current font, not how to change the font altogether.