# Font and application windows is extremely smaller for some applications in windows-10

Tags: windows-10

Some of the application in my windows machine shows a very small font size and it is not visible properly. What should be the reason for this problem? How do I make the font and size of that application bigger?

Screenshot of some of the application having such issues are:

This application is the Weka [Weka](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/%7Eml/weka/gui_explorer.html#:%7E:text=Weka%20Knowledge%20Explorer&text=Each%20of%20the%20major%20weka,be%20visualized%20in%20two%20dimensions.)

[image]

And another application is photoshop.

[image]

I also checked the solution mention [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1056631/fonts-extremely-small-in-some-applications-windows-10): but this application doesn't have an executable and it works from a batch file.

Comment: The batch file must call an executable.

Comment: no executable, it's a `.jar` file

Comment: Then it's java that's executing it. Use Task Manager to locate, or [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) by dragging the bull's-eye over the window.

Comment: that solution worked for photoshop, but not for that app.

Comment: oh wow! that was a hack. that worked. but isn't there any permanent solution for this to all apps?

Comment: That's not a hack, it's called sleuthing or forensics.