# How to change Explorer and Windows menu font size?

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I left my laptop (Windows 10 )with a friend so I don't know what was changed but the font size of the Windows menus and folder names in Windows Explorer became too large. The resolution is correct and the font is sharp.

I tried changing the resolution back and forth and changing the scaling and I restarted the laptop but still the issue persisted. I can't find the old feature for display to change the font size of text only.

Here are images that shows the issue:

[image: image showing the issue]

This is how the menu looks in Chrome:

[image: another image for the menu in chrome]

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/951199/windows-10-system-font-size-change?rq=1)?

Comment: @MSC I tried the below (written in Italic) but I didn't find Appearance and Personalisation in Control panel & overall I couldn't find any option like that (maybe it was removed in windows 10 creator update)

_Or if you want to specifically choose what you want the text size to change for, go to Control Panel > Appearance and Personalisation > Display > Make text and other items larger or smaller._

Comment: Cannot find that option anymore neither. Seems as if it was removed. Does changing the scaling change anything?

Comment: @MSC actually I tried with the scaling , it was 125% , I changed to 100% and back to 125% but it didn't fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
I found an easier way to solve this problem, this was caused on my laptop by pressing fn button with the + key on keyboard so pressing fn and - key reverts back to the smaller original windows font.

So I finally found the solution , you should change the registry key to the default value by the following steps:
You should copy the content of this section & put it in a notepad file with extension **.reg** then run it , it will revert the windows fonts to the default
"Window Metrics" Registry Fix (Restore defaults)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"IconTitleWrap"="1"
"Shell Icon Size"="32"
"BorderWidth"="-15"
"CaptionFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"CaptionHeight"="-330"
"CaptionWidth"="-330"
"IconFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"MenuFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"MenuHeight"="-285"
"MenuWidth"="-285"
"MessageFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"ScrollHeight"="-255"
"ScrollWidth"="-255"
"SmCaptionFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,\
  00,00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"SmCaptionHeight"="-330"
"SmCaptionWidth"="-330"
"StatusFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"AppliedDPI"=dword:00000060
"PaddedBorderWidth"="-60"
"IconSpacing"="-1125"
"IconVerticalSpacing"="-1125"
"MinAnimate"="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

No other solutions worked for me but this one:

- Go to display settings and turn on custom scaling and pick a value (I did 110)
- Reboot; it should look better upon restart
- Go to display settings and turn off custom scaling (forces you to sign out)
- Sign in and is fixed

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Skalierung und Anordnung]

Choose 125 % here to get the default. You will figure out the english terms...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, **actually my scaling is already 125%** , I tried changing this to 100% and back but still it didn't work