# How to reduce windows font below default set minimum

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to change the default windows text font (For folder name and details listing below the default minimum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a Registry tweak. Navigate to this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
```

The `IconFont` value determines the font face and size for most text. The first four bytes store the size. By default, it's 9 (the binary inverse of the sum of 2 and `F4 FF FF FF`). The bigger those bytes, the smaller the font size. For example, to make the font size be 4, replace `F4` with `F9` by positioning your cursor before `F9`, pressing Delete, and typing `F4`. Log off and back on for the changes to take effect. You can get very tiny text:

[image: Explorer with size 4 text]

The other values in that key have the same format. For more information on the various values, see [my other answer about this key](https://superuser.com/a/1069328/380318).