# What is the format of WindowMetrics fonts?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, fonts

I know it's possible to change the font settings via `WindowMetrics` and by experimentation in Windows 7 and changing various properties I found which parts are responsible for which setting. When I google for the keys all I can find is that they are in binary format (which I already know). For example [StatusFont](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960468.aspx)

```
Data type   Range                 Default value
REG_BINARY  Font name (in binary) MS Shell Dlg
```

Is there any more detailed description of this binary format so I don't have to rely only on my experiments? They seem to be correct but it'd be nice to have a confirmation.

Comment: @Biswa I know ;-) what I'm asking is whether there is a specification of that binary format. I can change the font or its size with LINQPad but I'm not entirely sure if what I'm doing and what I've found is really correct.

Comment: See this answer:: https://superuser.com/a/1069328/726810

Comment: If you understand C# or VB then you can open [Advanced System Font Changer](https://www.wintools.info/index.php/advanced-system-font-changer) in [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) to see how it changes registry.