# How do you change the grab zone for the top of the window?

Tags: windows-11, border

I know that I can go into the registry editor and change the border width and paddle border to change the side and bottom grab zones, but how do I change the top of the window grab zone?

This is where I changed the other borders: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics

Comment: in the same registry key, "Caption" refers to the title bar at the top of a window. Try adjusting the values for `CaptionHeight` and `CaptionWidth`  (or `SmCaptionHeight` for small captions). Note that text/fonts may not scale very well. See https://superuser.com/a/1069328/673426 for some more details